# How to restrict CefSharp Browser to given domain

Tags: wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I would like to prevent my application to display web pages other than from a certain domain (i.e. example.com).

My initial idea was to check the request URL in the **OnBeforeBrowse** event handler.

```
public bool OnBeforeBrowse(IWebBrowser browser, IRequest request, bool isRedirect)
{
  return !IsPageAllowed(request.Url);
}
```

This looks doable, except for the fact that all embedded resources on a allowed page are also triggering this event.
For example, i have a YouTube video embedded on my page there are two additional requests triggered by the video element.
If i cancel those requests, video is not rendered at all.
Here is a simple log output from my request:

```
15:09:22.5809442 - OnBeforeBrowse: http://example.com/, TransitionType=LinkClicked, isRedirect=False
15:09:22.6705460 - OnBeforeBrowse: http://www.youtube.com/embed/XYZ, TransitionType=LinkClicked, isRedirect=False
15:09:22.7715542 - OnBeforeBrowse: http://www.youtube.com/embed/XYZ, TransitionType=LinkClicked, isRedirect=True
15:09:25.1232542 - OnBeforeBrowse: http://not-allowed-domain.com TransitionType=LinkClicked, isRedirect=False
```

Further more, if i try to navigate away from the allowed page by clicking on a external link (with disabled restriction check), i get new event and **isRedirect** flag is set to False, which is quite confusing.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my project I've implemented the following solution:

1. There is necessity of the prepared list of trusted URLs or/and domains:
  ```
      HashSet whiteList = new HashSet() {
          "http://example.com/",
          "http://www.youtube.com/embed/",
          ...
      }
  ```
2. Filtering and blocking - in [**CefRenderProcessHandler.OnBeforeNavigation()**](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/CefRenderProcessHandler.html#OnBeforeNavigation%28CefRefPtr%3CCefBrowser%3E,CefRefPtr%3CCefFrame%3E,CefRefPtr%3CCefRequest%3E,NavigationType,bool%29)

Comment: Thanks for the hint @synh, i already had a **whiteList** for my explicit domains that i am restricting the browser to. Your answer gave me the idea to actually add another **resourceWhiteList** where i can name the allowed domains for all the resource sub-requests.

Answer (score 0):

In CEF use CefRequest.GetTransitionType():

```
  ///
  // Get the transition type for this request. Only available in the browser
  // process and only applies to requests that represent a main frame or
  // sub-frame navigation.
  ///
  /*--cef(default_retval=TT_EXPLICIT)--*/
  virtual TransitionType GetTransitionType() =0;
```

Check this value against bit flags that can tell you if this is a main frame or a subframe:

```
///
// Transition type for a request. Made up of one source value and 0 or more
// qualifiers.
///
typedef enum {
  ///
  // Source is a link click or the JavaScript window.open function. This is
  // also the default value for requests like sub-resource loads that are not
  // navigations.
  ///
  TT_LINK = 0,

  ///
  // Source is some other "explicit" navigation action such as creating a new
  // browser or using the LoadURL function. This is also the default value
  // for navigations where the actual type is unknown.
  ///
  TT_EXPLICIT = 1,

  ///
  // Source is a subframe navigation. This is any content that is automatically
  // loaded in a non-toplevel frame. For example, if a page consists of several
  // frames containing ads, those ad URLs will have this transition type.
  // The user may not even realize the content in these pages is a separate
  // frame, so may not care about the URL.
  ///
  TT_AUTO_SUBFRAME = 3,

  ///
  // Source is a subframe navigation explicitly requested by the user that will
  // generate new navigation entries in the back/forward list. These are
  // probably more important than frames that were automatically loaded in
  // the background because the user probably cares about the fact that this
  // link was loaded.
  ///
  TT_MANUAL_SUBFRAME = 4,

  ///
  // Source is a form submission by the user. NOTE: In some situations
  // submitting a form does not result in this transition type. This can happen
  // if the form uses a script to submit the contents.
  ///
  TT_FORM_SUBMIT = 7,

  ///
  // Source is a "reload" of the page via the Reload function or by re-visiting
  // the same URL. NOTE: This is distinct from the concept of whether a
  // particular load uses "reload semantics" (i.e. bypasses cached data).
  ///
  TT_RELOAD = 8,

  ///
  // General mask defining the bits used for the source values.
  ///
  TT_SOURCE_MASK = 0xFF,

  // Qualifiers.
  // Any of the core values above can be augmented by one or more qualifiers.
  // These qualifiers further define the transition.

  ///
  // Attempted to visit a URL but was blocked.
  ///
  TT_BLOCKED_FLAG = 0x00800000,

  ///
  // Used the Forward or Back function to navigate among browsing history.
  ///
  TT_FORWARD_BACK_FLAG = 0x01000000,

  ///
  // The beginning of a navigation chain.
  ///
  TT_CHAIN_START_FLAG = 0x10000000,

  ///
  // The last transition in a redirect chain.
  ///
  TT_CHAIN_END_FLAG = 0x20000000,

  ///
  // Redirects caused by JavaScript or a meta refresh tag on the page.
  ///
  TT_CLIENT_REDIRECT_FLAG = 0x40000000,

  ///
  // Redirects sent from the server by HTTP headers.
  ///
  TT_SERVER_REDIRECT_FLAG = 0x80000000,

  ///
  // Used to test whether a transition involves a redirect.
  ///
  TT_IS_REDIRECT_MASK = 0xC0000000,

  ///
  // General mask defining the bits used for the qualifiers.
  ///
  TT_QUALIFIER_MASK = 0xFFFFFF00,
} cef_transition_type_t;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Czarek, but this does not solves my problem. In my log output you can see that all requests have the same TransitionType value (LinkClicked) which seem to be the default in CefSharp (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp/TransitionType.cs). The comment for the default value explicitly states that this type is also applied to sub-resouce requests which is basically the source for my confusion and this question.