# Change browsing history for a ChromiumWebBrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I've got a WinForms app that uses a ChromiumWebBrowser control. The control will display content for a specific web page depending on what the application is being used for at the time, and after the user is finished with the site, it should close.

However, the user could currently use the back/forward buttons (or the context menu) to go back to a page in the browser that they shouldn't have access to any more. I need a way of wiping the history from the browser to prevent this.

I can't find any methods or properties within the control itself that can edit the history, and the best solution I've found so far is the OnLoadingStateChanged event (in which the back/forward buttons can be enabled or disabled). I can't figure out a sensible way of using this to track whether the user can go back or not though.

Is there a simple way to access the browsing history of the control?

Comment: Pretty sure it's `GetNavigationEntries`, [documentation](https://chromiumfx.bitbucket.io/api/html/M_Chromium_CfxBrowserHost_GetNavigationEntries.htm?). Not sure if you can remove entries. You could possibly try a [whitelist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346572/how-to-restrict-cefsharp-browser-to-given-domain).

Comment: Creating a new browser instance is the cleanest approach, there is no API to clear history.

Comment: @amaitland Any chance this has changed in the past 2.5 years?

Comment: @GeorgeVovos There was a discussion recently, https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1657/expose-ability-to-clear-all-web-storage-at#comment-53961756